# Parsing json code to a string in android using volley

Tags: android

i need help to parse this json code to actual strings using android volley. this is the json code:`[{"name":"Tayo","0":"Tayo","thread_name":"Welcome","1":"Welcome","post":"Hi there,","2":"Hi there,","post_time":"Sunday","3":"Sunday"},{"name":"Pete","0":"Pete","thread_name":"Welcome","1":"Welcome","post":"Hi,am pete","2":"Hi,am pete","post_time":"Monday","3":"Monday"}].`

I have tried other helps but not working. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "actual strings"?

Comment: "but not working" is not a sufficient problem description. Please clearly state what you have tried (also link to the solutions) and in how far the outcome is different from what you expect. You may want to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Remember:

> - if the .json content starts with { is considered as a Json Object.
> - if the .json content starts with [ is considered as a Json Array.

so you hava a `JsonArray` then you can parse your content like this way:

```
//Obtain the JsonArray
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myJsonContent);
// Get the JsonObjects inside JsonArray
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){                        
   JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// strData is the json data received.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strData);

    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String name = jsonObject.optString("name");
        String zero = jsonObject.optString("0");
        String thread_name = jsonObject.optString("thread_name");
        String one = jsonObject.optString("1");
        String post = jsonObject.optString("post");
        String two = jsonObject.optString("2");
        String post_time = jsonObject.optString("post_time");
        String three = jsonObject.optString("3");

       //Just an example
       arrayName.add(jsonObject.optString("name"));
    }
```

You can even use array to store data instead of the string.